# How to rename the default file Code.gs to forms.gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

The instruction no.3 in the document https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms says “Rename the Code.gs file to forms.gs.”, how do i do it?

Comment: @prabhu in this case [tag:gsuite] isn't relevant. It might be if the OP said that he is using a G Suite account or if the question is about a feature only available to those accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the code.gs file in the left sidebar and select rename and then rename to file.gs

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work anymore as the online IDE doesn't let you change the extension.

Comment: @rkagerer he isn't changing the extension but the file name